# Hibernate JPA @IdClass. Error: Unable to find column with logical name and its related supertables and secondary tables using

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have an Entity-class RepresentanteLegal with @Idclass anotation because I have a composite Primary Key.

Anotation is like:

```
@IdClass(PkRepresentanteLegal.class)
```

I have the following code for one of the key's attributes:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_RNREPLEG_PER")
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="CD_TIPOID", referencedColumnName = "CD_TIPOID", nullable=false, updatable=true, insertable=true),
        @JoinColumn(name="NR_IDENTI", referencedColumnName = "NR_IDENTI", nullable=false, updatable=true, insertable=true)
})
private Persona persona;
```

The problem is when I stop using @Idclass(put in comment), the deployment task of the project is done successful and all works correctly but when I use that anotation, I get the next error:

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: CD_TIPOID in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(RNPERSONA) and its related supertables and secondary tables

The PkRepresentanteLegal is:

```
public class PkRepresentanteLegal implements Serializable {
    private Persona persona;
    private DatosBasicos datosBasicos;
    private Date fcInicial;

   // Getters

   // Setters

}
```

Comment: I think that is a problem with `referencedColumnName`. I do not know how to change it when I use the `@IdClass`.

Comment: Can you post the full code for the classes?